# Asymptotic Distribution of Sample Mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

Suppose I have a discrete random variable $X$ which follows a geometric distribution on $x=0,1,2,...$ and I take a random sample from this distribution of size $n$.  What is the asymptotic distribution of $\bar X$?

I already know that $E(X)=\frac{1-p}{p}$ and $V(X)=\frac{1-p}{p^2}$.

This seems like an application of central limit theorem, so I'm sure that $\bar X$ converges to a normal distribution.  However, the part that's tripping me up is calculating the mean and variance of the normal distribution that it's converging to.  How do you do this?

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
E\bar{X}=E\left(n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^nX_{i}\right)
=n^{-1}\sum_1^nEX_i
=n^{-1}(nEX)=EX
$$
since the $X_i$ are identically distributed. Similarly,
$$
V(\bar{X})=V\left(n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^nX_{i}\right)
=n^{-2}\sum_1^nV(X_i)
=n^{-2}(nV(X))
=n^{-1}V(X)
$$
since the $X_i$ are independent and identically distributed.

Comment: If we're considering asymptotic convergence, then we're considering the limit as $n$ goes to infinity.  So if that is the calculated mean and variance of the normal distribution that it's converging to, then how can we say:

$X$~$N(E(X),\frac{V(X)}{n})$

when n is suddenly part of one of the parameters of the distribution?  I'm not understanding.

Or does this mean that the variance of the normal distribution that it converges to is zero?

Comment: @jippyjoe4 : In MathJax one writes $X\sim N(E(X), \frac{V(X)} n),$ not $X$~$N(E(X), \frac{V(X)} n),$ i.e the binary relation symbol should be inside of MathJax, not outside.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  But I still don't understand what distribution, exactly, $\bar X$ is converging to from this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$
\operatorname E( \, \overline X \, ) = \operatorname E\left( \frac {X_1+\cdots+X_n} n \right) = \frac 1 n \left( \operatorname E(X_1) + \cdots + \operatorname E(X_n) \right) = \frac 1 n \cdot n \operatorname E(X) = \operatorname E(X) 
$$
and
\begin{align}
\operatorname{var}\left( \sqrt n \cdot \overline X \right) = \operatorname{var} \left( \frac{X_1 + \cdots + X_n}{\sqrt n} \right) = \frac 1 n \left(\operatorname{var}(X_1) + \cdots + \operatorname{var}(X_n) \right) = \frac 1n \cdot n \operatorname{var}(X)
\end{align}

So $\displaystyle \dfrac{\overline X - \operatorname E(X)}{\sqrt n}$ has expected value $0$ and variance $1,$ and approaches $N(0,1)$ as $n\to\infty.$

Comment: So then I understand what the mean of $\bar X$ converges to as $n$ goes to infinity; but what happens to the variance?  Remember, I'm concerned specifically with the asymptotic distribution of $\bar X$, not any other function of it.